# I compared means of var X for two groups (t test). How calculate ROC for the classifier on these two groups based on variable X?

Tags: t-test, roc

How to calculate roc curve after performing t test (in sas or in R)? I compared means of variable X for two groups using t test. P-value is <0.05. How can I also calculate ROC curve for the classifier on these two groups based on variable X?

Comment: Welcome to this site! Can you provide more information about your setup? On the one hand, you mention a t-test to compare group means, on the other hand you talk about a classification task.

Comment: I don't think so (check also the doc of [PROC TTEST](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63033/HTML/default/viewer.htm#ttest_toc.htm) to see what sort of statistics a t-test usually returns). You would rather need a logistic regression if you have a binary outcome and use X as a predictor, but for a rather small sample it is unlikely you'll get reliable results.

Comment: Thank you! You are right -- it is actually about the classification task and I did not need to mention t test. Given: The values of variable X are higher on average for the treated group than for the control. The rule for classification should be in the form of comparison of variable X with a threshold. Is there a code for calculating ROC/AUC is SAS (or in R but better in SAS for me) for the described setting? And how to calculate also a confidence interval for AUC? Many thanks!

Comment: I run proc logistic in SAS and got the message: "There is a complete separation of data points. The maximum likelihood estimate does not exist.
 WARNING: The LOGISTIC procedure continues in spite of the above warning. Results shown are based on the last maximum likelihood iteration. Validity of the model fit is questionable."    I got the output with ROC=0.69. Not trustable value I think. On the other hand my understanding is that we do not need logistic regression to calculate ROC. Is there  a SAS Marco which addresses the issue directly?